# Fly ball hits a runner and goes out of play

Tags: baseball

What if a flyball touches a fielder then hits a runner and goes out of play? What's the call? Double grounded, right?

Comment: By "double grounded" do you mean the automatic award of two bases under MLB rule 5.06(b)(4)(G) which is commonly (and incorrectly) referred to as a "ground rule double"?